# HTML5 thumbnail slider

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am currently stuck at the part whenever I drag a HTML5 slider, it will show a thumbnail/small picture on the top or bottom of the slider. My slider is something like this...

```
 <input name="sliderStatus"  id="sliderStatus" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"/>
```

But how to do the thumbnail thingy? Any example? Thanks (:

Comment: Do you mean you want your slider to control scrolling of thumbnails ?

Comment: Hmm how to say... I have 10 pictures. Whenever I drag the slider, it will show respective thumbnail/picture based on the slider value. For instance, slider value 0 show picture 1, slider value 10 show picture 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to change thumbnail size according to the input `range` value.

You need to add `onchange` event listener to your range input and attach it to some callback, `updateThumbnail` for example:

```
<input name="sliderStatus" onchange="updateThumbnail(this)"  id="sliderStatus" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"/>
```

Then in your callback according to your value you can change thumbnail width:

```
function updateThumbnail(rangeInput) {
    var myImage = document.getElementById('someImage');
    myImage.width = rangeInput.value;
    myImage.height = rangeInput.value;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

According to your comment you need to change `step` attribute in your range input:
    step="10"

And for example modify your function to show your images:

```
function updateThumbnail(rangeInput) {
    var previousImage = document.getElementById('someImage' + (rangeInput.value - 10));
    if(previousImage) {
        previousImage.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var nextImage = document.getElementById('someImage' + rangeInput.value);
    nextImage.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Html markup for images should be:

```
<img src="pathToThumbnail" id="someImage0" style="display: block;">
<img src="pathToThumbnail" id="someImage10" style="display: none;">
<img src="pathToThumbnail" id="someImage20" style="display: none;">
...
<img src="pathToThumbnail" id="someImage100" style="display: none;">
```

See demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/CWd8S/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the scenario is that... I have 10 pictures. Whenever I drag the slider, it will show respective thumbnail/picture based on the slider value. For instance, slider value 0 show picture 1, slider value 10 show picture 2 and so on...